# Should I install an antivirus?

Tags: malware

Are builtin security features allied to secure user behavior enough to protect a Linux system?
Or should I install an antivirus software?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2751/the-myths-about-viruses-in-unix-linux , http://askubuntu.com/questions/10373/is-scanning-virus-needed-on-linux-distros

Comment: @iamsid Unix SE is not a dupe but useful. can't do anything about it on ask ubuntu even if it is.

Answer (score 2):

If its a company server then yes you should have anti-virus on it.  If you don't and it gets infected, you will either get your balls kicked, or get fired.  Neither is good.

At home, you can take more of a chance.  however, if you have windows machines, the Linux samba shares can act as safe haven for the virus and can keep reinfecting your windows machines.

Whilst it's quite rare to catch a linux virus or worm, but they do appear from time to time. Having a SSH port available to the internet is a major well known risk, there may well be other common attack methods for linux home servers.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, Linux doesn't requires an antivirus because it is nearly impossible for a virus to attack the Linux kernel. despite of this I prefer an antivirus like "clamav" for scanning some windows softwares which Linux users run through wine.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest a virus scanner (clamav) on server machines. You could run one also on desktop linux to stop spreading infections.