# Is there any Virus attack in Linux?

Tags: linux, malware

Is there any virus attack on any of the current distributions of Linux?

if there is any, how was it solved? have they used any anti virus programs which are available now?

Comment: have a look at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2751/the-myths-about-viruses-in-unix-linux

Comment: Could someone change the title into a question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a worm going around for an [exim4 vulnerability](http://lists.debian.org/debian-security-announce/2010/msg00181.html) in Debian: http://blog.bytemark.co.uk//2010/12/12/fresh-worm-food

Comment: The article cited only hypothesizes that a worm will go around, in "a matter of days".

Comment: As can be seen from the debian article, the defence is to fix the bug (defect). Where as for Microsoft Windows they have traditionally tried to detect the specific attack, so a new attack could be made that exploits the same vulnerability/bug/defect. (Microsoft have recently been fixing vulnerabilities, where this does not cause compatibility problems. However some of these bugs are so old that fixing them could break a lot of programs, and because Microsoft does not have the freedom to fix 3rd party programs, so that they will continue to work, they are reluctant to fix everything)

Answer (score 2):

There has never been a *single* major virus epidemic affecting Linux hosts "in the wild". The vast majority of virus attacks on Linux are just theoretical, and the few that have actually been implemented have never been able to spread beyond a handful of hosts.