# Malware for regular linux distros?

Tags: security, malware, hardening

I heard many stories that Linux doesn't have viruses/malwares, but I used linux for a short period of time and not a power user yet. I have security concerns and want to hear what you have to say about them. I know for a fact that there's ways to hack MacOS, with O.MG Elite for example, but is there this kind of malware for linux as well? Of course I'm talking about regular distros like manjaro for example and not some hard-to-install Qubes OS. And I'm not talking about how many of them exist, because obviously windows is way more popular(and shitty) so most malware are targeted it and other popular OS such as MacOS.

Please feel free to educate me on the topic :)

Comment: `feel free to educate me` ... this is a question and answer site for answering focused questions about Nix ... it is not a tutorial forum

Comment: I was just trying to say that I may not see the whole picture and probably missed something, so if you can to add something I would be glad

Answer (score 0):

Take a look through this question and answer here: [The myths about malware in Unix / Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2751/the-myths-about-malware-in-unix-linux?rq=1)

In short, yes it is possible for malware to be created for Linux distributions but for a variety of reasons, it's not as common or widespread as malware for Windows.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that thread when I was googling. Thanks a lot meijin3, very, very helpful